# filter angular js array by multiple columns and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting

i am trying to filter an angular js array using multiple columns .

e.g  | filter:{sender: 'fred', reciever: 'josh'} | filter:{sender: 'josh', reciever: 'fred'}

But it doesn't seem to work, please view my complete code below

```
      <div ng-repeat="msg in messages | filter:{sender: 'fred', reciever: 'josh'} | filter:{sender: 'josh', reciever: 'fred'}">

      Sender : {{ msg.sender }} MSg : {{ msg.msg }} Reciever : {{ msg.reciever }}
      </div>

      </div>

      <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.messages = [
      {sender:'fred', reciever:'josh', msg:'HI'},
      {sender:'josh', reciever:'fred', msg:'i DEY'}, 
      {sender:'fred', reciever:'josh', msg:'Hello'}
      ];
      });
      </script>
```

Here is the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c8uvrbvj/

Comment: creating custom filter would be an great option to go.. by passing `property` & `name ` to be filter out

Comment: @PankajParkar, can u give me a sample custom filter that can work for me ?

Comment: @Meiko The function worked well, but after adding a new value to the array like {sender:'josh', receiver:'racheal', msg:'hw re u?'} , the new values showed up . what i was aiming to achieve is to display the message between where the sender = ''josh' and receiver = "fred" or sender = "fred" and receiver = "josh" . Thanks for your help ...

Comment: @Meiko The code is running fine , but i am having little issues with passing variables into the filter object <div ng-repeat="msg in (messages | myfilter:[{sender: user1, reciever: user2},{sender: user2, reciever: user1}])">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to filter the messages in the controller. DOM filters can cause performance problems. see: [Using Controller $filters to prevent $digest performance issues](https://toddmotto.com/use-controller-filters-to-prevent-digest-performance-issues/)

But this basically works:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.messages = [
        {sender:'fred', receiver:'josh', msg:'HI'},
        {sender:'josh', receiver:'fred', msg:'i DEY'}, 
        {sender:'josh', receiver:'racheal', msg:'hw re u2?'},
        {sender:'barack', receiver:'angela', msg:'Dear'}, 
        {sender:'fred', receiver:'josh', msg:'Hello'}, 
        {sender:'angela', receiver:'barack', msg:'Moin'},
        {sender:'josh', receiver:'racheal', msg:'hw re u?'}
    ];
}).filter('myfilter', function() {
  return function(input, filter) {
    return input.filter(function(e1){
      return filter.find(function(e2) {
          return e1.sender === e2.sender && e1.receiver === e2.receiver;
      });
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="msg in (messages | myfilter:[{sender: 'fred', receiver: 'josh'},{sender: 'josh', receiver: 'fred'}])">

Sender : {{ msg.sender }} MSg : {{ msg.msg }} Reciever : {{ msg.reciever }}
</div>

</div>
```

It follows a solution without DOM filtering, I think a better approach:

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    
    function filter(input, filter) {
        return input.filter(function(e1){
            return filter.find(function(e2) {
                return e1.sender === e2.sender && e1.receiver === e2.receiver;
            });
        });
    }
    
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        
        var messages = [
            {sender:'fred', receiver:'josh', msg:'HI'},
            {sender:'josh', receiver:'fred', msg:'i DEY'},
            {sender:'josh', receiver:'racheal', msg:'hw re u2?'},
            {sender:'barack', receiver:'angela', msg:'Dear'},
            {sender:'fred', receiver:'josh', msg:'Hello'},
            {sender:'angela', receiver:'barack', msg:'Moin'},
            {sender:'josh', receiver:'racheal', msg:'hw re u?'}
        ];
        var name1 = 'fred';
        var name2 = 'josh';
        var myFilter = [{sender: name1, receiver: name2},{sender: name2, receiver: name1}];

        $scope.messages = filter(messages, myFilter);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="msg in messages">

        Sender : {{ msg.sender }} MSg : {{ msg.msg }} Reciever : {{ msg.reciever }}
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The function worked well, but after adding a new value to the array like {sender:'josh', receiver:'racheal', msg:'hw re u?'} , the new values showed up . what i was aiming to achieve is to display the message between where the sender = ''josh' and receiver = "fred" or sender = "fred" and receiver = "josh" . Thanks for your help ...

Comment: see the edited code... could not reproduce that ... where did you add {sender:'josh', receiver:'racheal', msg:'hw re u?'}?

Comment: The code is running fine , but i am having little issues with passing variables into the filter object <div ng-repeat="msg in (messages | myfilter:[{sender: user1, reciever: user2},{sender: user2, reciever: user1}])">

Comment: I think you should filter the messages in the controller or in a service. It is much better for your performance and easier to implement. You could use this function "function(input, filter) {..." after giving it a name. I think it does not make sense to do the filtering in the template.

Comment: even after using the function in the controller it didn't work with variables , but works well with static values ..

Comment: ok :) I updated my answer to demonstrate that stuff, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot i can now pass variables into the object . But the messages array is not filtering properly according to messages btw josh and fred only . pls here is my demo on jsfiddle . Thanks https://jsfiddle.net/c8uvrbvj/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot , you have been most helpful today , everything is finally working . i owe you a beer . cheers !

Comment: hello @Meiko , its been a long time . The angular js filter you wrote for me a month ago works fine on web and android 5.0 , but doesn't work when i emulate it on a mobile phone with android below 5.0 , every statement below the filter never executes , once i remove the filter they do . it works well when i run it from a web browser and android 5.0 and above , do you have any idea why ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: i realized the issue is with the .find() function , could you help me with that ??? thanks